Layout with Map Rotation using QGIS
I've created a map layout in QGIS 3.38 as I've done many times before. For the first time I've used a map rotation. All appears fine until I try to export the map to PDF. The map disappears from the layout and all other items remain. When I look at the properties< Scale has been replaced with 'nan'. The Extents have all been replaced with 'nan'. In Position and Size 'Y' and 'Height' have both been replaced with 9999999.000. 'X' and 'Width' remain correct. I try correcting these but it doesn't allow it or it makes no difference. I also tested exporting to an image with the same result. The map contains vector data and an ecw image. Layouts without rotation works fine.
What is the cause of the problem?

Is map rotation defined by expression?

How did you rotate the map?

It was set in the Main Properties, Map Rotation for the map item in the Layout window. I also tried setting the rotation in the main map canvas. Both failed. I'm not an experienced QGIS user so perhaps I'm misunderstanding how it works.
